# Component with v-once still re-renders when a value of a prop object property is changing

Tags: vue.js

Is it a right behavior If I pass an object to a prop of **v-once** component and change value of some object property, component will still re-render? Why component internal Watcher is still re-rendering component?

I have tried to pass **primitive** as a prop and it works like I expected, component is not re-rendering, but with **object**:

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="obj.isVisible = !obj.isVisible">
    toggle visibility
  </button>
  <HelloWorld v-once :obj="obj"/>
</div>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```html
<div>
 <div v-if="obj.isVisible">it is visible</div>
</div>
```

[codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-60lxp?fontsize=14)

I expected that HelloWorld will not be re-rendering after click.

Answer (score 2):

Put `v-once` in root element of `HelloWorld` component

```html
<div v-once>
 <div v-if="obj.isVisible">it is visible</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ty, I is working, but I am still expecting to use it like ```<component v-once></component>``` , because in your case we are excluding possibility to reuse this component without v-once. We can add v-bind="attrs" to this example to make this component transparent... but it seems like workaround.

Comment: The component can always trigger an update based on its internal state (data/props), v-once just says that if an update is scheduled on the parent component, it will be ignored.